# How do I make a Werewolf in Sims 2?

Tags: the-sims-2

So I was playing Sims 2, and my 1st Sim is a witch. And she made a Lycanthropy Potion, and I can't get a Sim to drink it. How can I?

Comment: A quick [google search](https://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=OSpWVZvlAozF8gf684Aw&gws_rd=ssl#q=the+sims+2+werewolf) suggest you need The pets expansion to do it. You got it?

Comment: Yes, I have the Sims 2 Life With Pets.

Answer (score 3):

The Lycanthropy potion cures lycanthropes, it doesn't turn a Sim into a lycanthrope. To become a werewolf, you must be Savaged by a werewolf Sim or bitten by the Leader of the Pack, who only shows up at night. If you are having trouble finding the Leader of the Pack, you can use `boolprop testingCheatsEnabled true` from the console to turn on cheat mode, then shift click the mailbox to summon the Leader of the Pack. You must build up a relationship between the Sim and the Leader of the Pack to get bitten.

If you later decide to cure the Sim of lycanthropy, you've already discovered how to make the potion to do so. However, only a Sim you control can be directed to drink the potion. You cannot use Influence to make a Sim drink the potion. This means that, if your witch and your werewolf Sims are from different households, you have to transfer the potion to the werewolf Sim, then send that Sim home and switch to playing that Sim. Townies who are also werewolves can't be cured unless you ask them to move in (to make them playable) or use a cheat to take control of the townie.

Comment: This is not really part of my answer, but is a side note: if you want a potion that changes a sim into a werewolf, there are downloadable potions, for example the [Lycanthrope Blood potion](http://modthesims.info/d/201384) on Mod the Sims.